# How to transform a dataframe grouped by into another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation, purrr

I have a dataframe

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  "player_name" = c("bob","michel","bob","michel","bob","anna"),
  "player_number" = c("1","2","1","2","1","4"),
  "position" = c("1","2","2","1","2","1"),
  "match" = c("match1","match1","match2","match2","match3","match3")
)
```

```
  player_name player_number position  match
1         bob             1        1 match1
2      michel             2        2 match1
3         bob             1        2 match2
4      michel             2        1 match2
5         bob             1        2 match3
6        anna             4        1 match3
```

and I want to transform it into this dataframe

```
   match position1 position2
1 match1         1         2
2 match2         2         1
3 match3         4         1
```

- I will have up to 12 positions so I may not want to hardcode
- I got a feeling I can use `purr` and `group_map` for that but what exact function ?

Maybe you can point me to the doc and the right function in purr so I can learn first ? (before answering :)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `pivot_wider`:

```
library(tidyverse)

pivot_wider(df1, match, 
        names_from = position, values_from = player_number, names_prefix = "Position")
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  match  Position1 Position2
  <chr>  <chr>     <chr>    
1 match1 1         2        
2 match2 2         1        
3 match3 4         1
```

In base R you would do:

```
reshape(df1, v.names = 'player_number', 
         timevar = 'position', dir='wide', idvar = 'match', drop='player_name')

   match player_number.1 player_number.2
1 match1               1               2
3 match2               2               1
5 match3               4               1
```

with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
dcast(df1, match~position, value.var = 'player_number')
    match 1 2
1: match1 1 2
2: match2 2 1
3: match3 4 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `acast` from `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
acast(df1, match ~ position, value.var = 'player_number')
```

---

Or use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(player_number ~ match + position, df1)
```